# SQL Pivot based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

Hi I am New to SQL Pivoting

I have different requirement where i need to Pivot data based on multiple columns(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) based on Categories for Programs. Please advice how can I achieve this?

All examples are based on a single column( eg. SUM(Q1) FOR CategoryID IN ([People], [IT], [Travel])

How do i pivot it based on Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4?

Input

[image: Input]

Output

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result that you want you will have to apply both the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` functions.

The *unpivot* function will convert your `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, and `Q4` columns into rows. Once that is done, you will apply the *pivot* function.

The unpivot code will be similar to this:

```
select programid,
  col + '_'+ category cat_col,
  value
from yourtable 
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e5a1/2). This gives a result:

```
| PROGRAMID |   CAT_COL |  VALUE |
----------------------------------
|       366 | Q1_People | 109034 |
|       366 | Q2_People |  25418 |
|       366 | Q3_People | 101130 |
|       366 | Q4_People |  54787 |
```

You can see that this query creates a new column name to pivot which has the category value and the quarter name.

Once you have this result, you can apply the pivot function:

```
select *
from
(
  select programid,
    col + '_'+ category cat_col,
    value
  from yourtable 
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
  ) unpiv
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for cat_col in (Q1_People, Q2_People, Q3_People, Q4_People,
                  Q1_IT, Q2_IT, Q3_IT, Q4_IT,
                  Q1_Travel, Q2_Travel, Q3_Travel, Q4_Travel)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/751bc/3). This gives the result:

```
| PROGRAMID | Q1_PEOPLE | Q2_PEOPLE | Q3_PEOPLE | Q4_PEOPLE | Q1_IT | Q2_IT | Q3_IT | Q4_IT | Q1_TRAVEL | Q2_TRAVEL | Q3_TRAVEL | Q4_TRAVEL |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       366 |    109034 |     25418 |    101130 |     54787 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |      1195 |       613 |      1113 |      1195 |
```